# Get list of date evenly spaced

Tags: python, date

I would like to get a list with today date and dates 1, 2, 3 and 4 quarters in the past (one year). But the output i got is repeating the same date a given number of time. Any help would be great please.

Output:

```
[datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 09), datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 10), datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 10), datetime.datetime(2019, 01, 09), datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 10)]
```

My code:

```
date_list = [one_year - timedelta(days=91) for x in range(5)]
```

The output:

```
[datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 10, 14, 36, 9, 623047), datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 10, 14, 36, 9, 623047), datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 10, 14, 36, 9, 623047), datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 10, 14, 36, 9, 623047),  datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 10, 14, 36, 9, 623047)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
date_list = [one_year - timedelta(days=x * 91) for x in range(5)]
```